# Nuxt JS css file not included in build

Tags: css, nuxt.js

Trying to include a CSS file in the build output. `yarn dev` works fine and the CSS file is bundled up.

But `yarn build` and then `yarn start`, the CSS isn't there.

I have this in the nuxt.config.js file

```
css: [
    '~/assets/css/leaflet.css'
  ],
build: {
    extractCSS: {
      allChunks: true
    },
    extend (config, ctx) {
    }
  }
```

nor is it included if I `import` the file inside the .vue file:

```
`import '~/assets/css/leaflet.css`
```

Only if I put it all in a `<style>` block does it get picked up buy the `build` job but that's not ideal.

Thanks

Comment: Did you find the solution? I am facing the same issue.